# How to use fiddler to debug?

Tags: javascript, debugging, fiddler

I have a webpage when it finished on the left bottom there's a warning says:Done, but with errors on the page. I double click it and it told me:

```
Line:628
Char:100
Error: Expected ')'
Code: 0
URL:.....
```

I knew Fiddler is a good tool to debug. I download it and try to debug. The line IE told me I just can't find anything that's missing ')'

Can someone tell me how to debug this?

Comment: Did you ever get this resolved successfully? Do you still need help with this?

Answer (score 3):

IE may be interpreting line numbers differently than you expect. Firebug is probably a better tool for helping debug this type of problem.

Comment: Unfortunately I've had to debug some applications that have calls not visible in Firebug, Chrome's debugger, or IE's debugger, because the're made by the extension outside of the browser's frame, so learning to debug in Fiddler which sees this calls when run as an external application would be useful.

Answer (score 2):

Fiddler is good at capturing what goes across the stream. It's like comparing a hammer and a wrench. Each is the right tool for a specific job.

Answer (score 1):

If using IE8, hit F12 to bring up the debugger.  You can start debugging and have it show you exactly where your error is occurring.

The open ( is probably occurring several lines before the missing ).